# Is there a way to write multiple lines of code in one line

Tags: python-3.x

In javascript there is a way to write multiple lines of code in one, like this:

```
console.log('yes'); console.log('no'); console.log('oh yeeaaah');
```

I was wondering if this was possible in python3, is it? And if it is, how?

Comment: Just dont.... even in javascript this isn't a great idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, can you write multiple lines of code in one line like in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343639/in-python-can-you-write-multiple-lines-of-code-in-one-line-like-in-matlab)

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't know there was a similar question asked... I know you guys don't like that... Btw I was just wondering, I despise of it as much as you do as it makes your code quite messy, it was just a question I didn't know the answer to and couldn't find one to, perhaps I didn't look that good, thanks for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do it in Python, like this:
`print("Hello");print("world")`.
**BUT**, I would highly discourage you to do it as it can easily lead to hard to read, messy, and unorganized code. If you can not do it, don't, especially in Python. You can look at PEP8 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is like this `print("Hello"),print("World!")` that would also work.